# How to tokenize using strtok regardless of whether there is a string or not in that line - C

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok

I am trying to read the last word in each line of a file. I can get the desired result when the lines in the file look like `2011/1/29,,0 ,1063` , but not when the lines in the file look like `2011/1/29,summer,0 ,1063`

I thought I am tokenizing every ",", so the string in the line should not affect my result but it does. Anybody knows why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (){
    FILE* fp;
    char tmpline[256]; 
    char* separator2 =",";
    char* words;
    int i = 0; 

    fp = fopen("printer.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(tmpline, 256, fp) != NULL){

        printf(tmpline);
        if (tmpline != NULL){ 
            words = strtok(tmpline,separator2); //get first token 
            while (words != NULL) { /* walk through other tokens */
                for (i=0; i<3; i++) { 
                    if (i==2) {
                        printf( "papers: %s\n",words);                      
                    }
                    words= strtok(NULL, separator2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is part of the output

```
// 2011/1/29,,0 ,1063
// papers: 1063

// 2011/1/31,,2 ,991
// papers: 991

// 2011/2/1,,3 ,1789
// papers: 1789

// 2011/2/2,spring,4 ,974
// papers: 4 
// papers: (null)
// 2011/2/3,spring,5 ,1119
// papers: 5 
// papers: (null)
// 2011/2/4,spring,6 ,617
```

Comment: did not check you code, but are you using a fixed number for token? consecutive delimiters are considered one.

Comment: If you are going to use `strtok()`, you *really* need to read the documentation (manpage). It is not at all intuitive, particularly with regards to cumulated delimiters.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't think I have. How do I do that? do I have to count manually? :/

Comment: `if (i==2)`...hmm..seems my assumption is correct... tho I really did not get the logic behind using `i`, at all.

Comment: Consider finding the delimiters with `strchr()` or `strpbrk()` and dividing up the string yourself instead... it's only slightly more effort, and you won't miss any that way.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you for answering so quickly! well I can't think of another way of just printing the last number, that is why I used an i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will store the pointer to each valid token. When you have no more tokens, use the one stored. I also added some more delimiters, to include whitespace, one reason is because `fgets` retains the `newline` that was in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){                                // correct signature
    FILE* fp;
    char tmpline[256]; 
    char* separator2 =", \t\r\n";               // added more delimiters
    char* words;
    char *lastword;                             // previous valid token

    fp = fopen("printer.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(tmpline, 256, fp) != NULL) {
        lastword = NULL;
        words = strtok(tmpline,separator2);     // get first token 
        while (words != NULL) {                 // walk through other tokens
            lastword = words;                   // remeber previous token
            words= strtok(NULL, separator2);    // get next token
            }
        if(lastword != NULL) {
            printf( "papers: %s\n", lastword);                      
        }
    }

    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple.. thank you very much! I can learn so much from this code. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, sorry I forgot to advise about checking `fp` after opening the file, it's usually essential task.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather read char by char using fgetc. Than when you find the space you start to save what the word is. Its just easier, nothing special.